# Set the root directory in cmd.exe using java

Tags: java, cmd, processbuilder

This is one way to run cmd.exe using java:

```
String command="cmd /c start cmd.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

How to enforce `command` to run cmd.exe from the root directory `C:\` ?

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder`; with it you can set the working directory of the new process you want to launch

Comment: Ok, i tried to used cd\ within String command since cd\ gets the root but it didn't work.

Comment: `command="c:\cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe"`

Comment: Thanks kajacx, but String in java doesn't allow "\" without parameter !!! I tried your line but doesn't work either

Comment: @kajacx That will only tell the OS where to find the command, not change the execution context

Comment: `command="c:\\cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe"` note the \\ instead of the \c @kajacx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by others, consider using **[ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)**.

### Code:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", "start");
processBuilder.directory(new File("C:\\"));
try {
    processBuilder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```